# SD applications return to Internal Memory

Tags: sd-card, 8.1-oreo

I have a Samsung J7 prime with Android 8.1, the issue is that my applications can be moved normally to external storage, but then it appears again in the internal memory. (when google play store updates the apps). Is there any way to avoid that?

Answer (score 0):

To avoid updating apps it can be changed in settings when updating is allowed. Or u can shut it down all together then manually run scans to pick and choose which app you want to update.